# What's the best way to create fragment anchors in GitHub markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to create fragment anchors to use for link destinations in GitHub markdown. I'm trying to avoid embedding HTML  elements since best-practice markdown is to avoid inline HTML.

I'm not talking about heading anchors (though if a heading has non-letter characters, getting auto-generated heading links to work can be a trial-and-error headache). I need to have anchors for arbitrary locations in a .md file.

I've come across GitHub documentation for [link reference definitions](https://github.github.com/gfm/#link-reference-definitions), but that documentation doesn't really explain clearly how to create an anchor. I tried following [Example 168](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-168) of creating a link reference without specifying a destination, but that doesn't create an anchor; it just creates a "road to nowhere", so to speak.

What's the best option?

Comment: You would have to use HTML. Only headers give you a markdown way to generate an anchor automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support custom anchors out-of-the-box (however, some markdown flavors may do) so you have to use HTML.

Create an anchor:

```
<a name="location"></a>
```

Refer to this anchor:

```
Take me to something [custom](#location)
```

Comment: It's annoying that this is the answer :-(