# Reference a displayed image in README.md

Tags: github, markdown

I have an image in markdown:

```
![Tabs](https://raw.github.com/dbpedia/DBpedia-Spotlight-Dashboard/main/images/doc/1_tabs.png)
```

How can I reference that image like:

```
[Figure 2](-reference-) shows the 4 main tabs of the dashboard
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/how-to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Github markdown, you can use HTML tag `a`, set with the `name` on the object and `href`

On the object/image:

```
<a name="tabs">![Tabs](https://raw.github.com/dbpedia/DBpedia-Spotlight-Dashboard/main/images/doc/1_tabs.png)</a>
```

On the link text:

```
<a href="#tabs">Figure 2</a>
```

You may need to define unique `name` for every components and also unique among the headings.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use html to create an anchor: see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058879/341994

But I doubt that this will work, because GitHub sanitizes your html and will probable neutralize the anchor. In that case, the answer is that what you're trying to do is impossible using the tool you're using.

Personally, I use `kramdown` to generate raw html from Markdown. That way, I can do the sort of thing you're after.